# How to find out the virtualization type of an linux VPS?

Tags: linux, virtualization, vps, terminal

Having access to an VPS, i need to know which type of virtualization it is running from the terminal.

How can determine the virtualization platform that my VM is running on? (OpenVZ, Xen, KVM, etc?)

Comment: I've only used KVM - I'd hope that the others are similar - Assuming you are using Linux, in KVM you can just look through the bootlog for a line like "Booting paravirtulized kernel on KVM".

Comment: In my case all boot logs are empty... and dmesg dosen't show any output. =/

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`hostnamectl` is your friend (requires *`systemd`*).

A few examples:

**Laptop without any virtualization**

```
$ hostnamectl status
   Static hostname: earth.gangs.net
         Icon name: computer-laptop
           Chassis: laptop
        Machine ID: 18a0752e1ccbeef09da51ad17fab1f1b
           Boot ID: beefdc99969e4a4a8525ff842b383c62
  Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
            Kernel: Linux 4.4.0-66-generic
      Architecture: x86-64
```

**Xen**

```
$ hostnamectl status
   Static hostname: pluto.gangs.net
         Icon name: computer-vm
           Chassis: vm
        Machine ID: beef39aebbf8ba220ed0438b54497609
           Boot ID: beefc71e97ed48dbb436a470fe1920e1
    Virtualization: xen
  Operating System: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
            Kernel: Linux 3.13.0-37-generic
      Architecture: x86-64
```

**OpenVZ**

```
$ hostnamectl status
   Static hostname: mars.gangs.net
         Icon name: computer-container
           Chassis: container
        Machine ID: 55296cb0566a4aaca10b8e3a4b28beef
           Boot ID: 1bb259b0eb064d9eb8a22d112211beef
    Virtualization: openvz
  Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
       CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:centos:centos:7
            Kernel: Linux 2.6.32-042stab120.16
      Architecture: x86-64
```

**KVM**

```
$ hostnamectl status
   Static hostname: mercury.gangs.net
         Icon name: computer-vm
           Chassis: vm
        Machine ID: beeffefc50ae499881b024c25895ec86
           Boot ID: beef9c7662a240b3b3b04cef3d1518f0
    Virtualization: kvm
  Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
       CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:centos:centos:7
            Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-514.10.2.el7.x86_64
      Architecture: x86-64
```

Comment: I just get `Failed to create bus connection: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 8):

Unless the VM host is lying to you it can generally be figured out by inspecting the "hardware" the VM guest is seeing.

Easiest is probably to use a program like [virt-what](http://people.redhat.com/~rjones/virt-what/), which will do the parsing for you. Here I'm blindly assuming that you are running some kind of Linux based distribution by the way.

Might also be worth taking a look at puppet's [facter](https://github.com/puppetlabs/facter), which too uses similar techniques to determine in what kind of VM environment it's running.

Or you could you ask whoever you happen to be renting the VPS from? :-)

Comment: virt-what worked to me. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I looked at `facter`. It calls `virt-what`!

Answer (score 5):

Use the `virt-what` command to determine the type of virtualization technology the system is using.

See: http://people.redhat.com/~rjones/virt-what/

Answer (score 4):

Systemd includes systemd-detect-virt

Answer (score 2):

Debian comes with this small package for detecting virtualisation type:

```
$ sudo apt-get install virt-what
$ virt-what
```

and little bigger because of Perl dependencies:

```
$ sudo apt-get install imvirt
$ imvirt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `dmidecode` which will show you system hardware info and other.

Comment: `dmidecode` is empty for my VPS. `lshw` is mostly empty. `virt-what` shown `openvz` ))