# SELinux is set to permissive but it's disabled, how to enable it?

Tags: vps, selinux

I want to enable SELinux on my VPS but I can't do it.

**/etc/selinux/config :**

```
# This file controls the state of SELinux on the system.
# SELINUX= can take one of these three values:
# enforcing - SELinux security policy is enforced.
# permissive - SELinux prints warnings instead of enforcing.
# disabled - No SELinux policy is loaded.
SELINUX=permissive
# SELINUXTYPE= can take one of these two values:
# default - equivalent to the old strict and targeted policies
# mls     - Multi-Level Security (for military and educational use)
# src     - Custom policy built from source
SELINUXTYPE=default

# SETLOCALDEFS= Check local definition changes
SETLOCALDEFS=0
```

As you can see, I did not set it to `disabled` in the config file. But it is disabled:

```
root@vpsxxxxx:/home/username# sestatus
SELinux status:                 disabled
```

I restarted the VPS from the provider's website client interface, but it is still disabled.

Answer (score 3):

Which software implements your VPS? 
Maybe OpenVZ?
OpenVZ is incomparible with selinux https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Virtualization/OpenVZ

Comment: I don't know. How do I see that ? I have never heard of OpenVZ. My VPS provider is OVH.

Comment: Try with this question/answer https://serverfault.com/questions/595471/how-to-find-out-the-virtualization-type-of-an-linux-vps